# concatenating aliases in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, alias

I would like to concatenate aliases. So for example, if I have the following:

```
alias aliasone="cat"
alias aliastwo="/etc/passwd"
```

I would like to be able to type in the shell something like "aliasone+aliastwo" and then the following command will be executed:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: When you want to do something a bit complex, functions are better than aliases.

Comment: If this general area (of building up shell commands via composition) is of interest to you, I strongly suggest reading BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases are only for command substitution. If you want to have shorthand for arguments, use shell variables.

```
file=/etc/passwd
cat "$file"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the "alias" from the second line. That is:

```
alias aliasone="cat"
folder="/etc/passwd"
```

And then you can write:

```
aliasone $folder
```

The problem is that alias evaluate commands; but in the second alias there is no command. In the case of a parameter is better to use a variable. If you have a more particular situation (e.g. you are are inside a script) tell us so we can give a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run several aliases at the same time, one after another.
I might be wrong, but if this is the case, the easy solution will be to use && in a new alias.
For example you have two existing ones:
alias cdtomydir='cd /home/mydir'
alias listfilesindir = 'll'

then you are able to combine the two above into a third alias by using &&:
alias cdtomydirandlistfiles = 'cdtomydir && listfilesindir'

Answer (score 0):

you can do this: **alias aliasone='cat /etc/passwd'** then just type **aliasone** and that's it then if you're going to use cat looking elsewhere then type **alias aliastwo='cat /etc/shadow'** for example. Anyway just change path and that's it and make sure that aliases are different and keep on mind that words used for commands aren't reserved.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most effective solution, but it still works,
instead of concatenating 2 aliases, an alias is replaced by the command

```
 alias alias_name 'command 1 ; command 2'
```

then execute in Terminal

```
alias_name
```

and it does the trick

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:**

```
alias ccat='cat $1'
```

**Step 2:**

```
ccat /etc/passwd
```

**Output>>**

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin.............
```